# Using ngx-pipes in Angular 2 with jhipster throws Module parse failed

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, jhipster

I'm trying to use [ngx-pipes](https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes) with jhipster 4.0.7 and Angular 2. I am seeing following error

```
ERROR in ./~/ngx-pipes/src/app/pipes.module.ts
Module parse failed: /Users/me/Projects/git/app-ui/node_modules/ngx-pipes/src/app/pipes.module.ts Unexpected character '@' (8:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import {NgBooleanPipesModule} from './pipes/boolean/index';
|
| @NgModule({
|   declarations: [],
|   imports: [],
 @ ./~/ngx-pipes/src/app/index.js 5:9-34
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ dll vendor
```

TS part of webpack looks as below

```
{
   test: /\.ts$/,
   loaders: [
       'angular2-template-loader',
       'awesome-typescript-loader'
   ],
   exclude: ['node_modules/generator-jhipster']
},
```

Without adding ngx-pipes, compile is successful.

I referred to [this](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker/issues/136#issuecomment-276928469) github solution that I guess is asking to exclude node_modules except those starting with `ng2` or `ngx`.

When I changed excludes to

```
exclude: [/node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+|ngx-.+))/]
```

I got errors as below.

```
ERROR in ./~/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts
Module parse failed: /myfolder/git/myproject/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts Unexpected token (15:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| and limitations under the License.
| ***************************************************************************** */
| namespace Reflect {
|     "use strict";
|
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts 4:0-35
```

How do I fix this? I created a [ticket](https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes/issues/43) with ngx-pipes but I guess this is a common problem not related to ngx-pipes.

Comment: Have you looked at the example about leaflet in your generated README.md? Try to import ngx-pipes into vendor.ts to let webpack know about it.

Comment: I have done that. I added ng2-bootstrap. So I got that flow. The issue is when I add ngx-pipes

Comment: Also, as you can see the first code block, `ngx-pipes` got picked from vendor.ts and that is when it reports error.